# Identities involving the del operator

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-fields

"Which of these identities hold for all vector fields $\mathbf{F}$ and functions $f$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$ with continuous first and second derivatives?"

- $\nabla\times(\nabla f)=0$ (Ans.: True)
- $\nabla.(\nabla\times\mathbf{F})=0$ (Ans.: True)
- $\nabla(\nabla.\mathbf{F})=0$ (Ans.: False)
- $\nabla\times(\nabla.\mathbf{F})=0$ (Ans.: False)

Can someone please explain how you would prove/disprove these identities?

Comment: You do that by applying the definitions.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat{\mathbf{i}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\hat{\mathbf{j}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ and $\mathbf{F} = F_x\hat{\mathbf{i}}+F_y\hat{\mathbf{j}}+F_z\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ into the identities. E.g.:
\begin{align}
\nabla\times(\nabla f)&=\left\vert\array{
\hat{\mathbf{i}} & \hat{\mathbf{j}} & \hat{\mathbf{k}} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} 
}\right\vert
= \left[\begin{array}\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial z}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial z} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial z}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial z} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} 
\end{array}\right]
=0 \\
\nabla.(\nabla\times\mathbf{F})&= 
\left[\begin{array}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{array}\right]
.\left[\begin{array}\\
\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} 
\end{array}\right]
= \frac{\partial^2 F_z}{\partial x\partial y}-\frac{\partial^2 F_y}{\partial x\partial z}+\frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial y\partial z}-\frac{\partial^2 F_z}{\partial x\partial y}+\frac{\partial^2 F_y}{\partial x\partial z}-\frac{\partial^2 F_x}{\partial y\partial z}=0
\end{align}